# AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'getElementById'

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, automation

I'm Setting up my auto-commenter bot for youtube. I am unable to send_keys to the comment box. Here is a copy of my current code.

```
commentr.getElementById('simplebox-placeholder').innerHTML = 'your comment text here'
```

Here is the error that occurs.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users", line 73, in <module>
commentr.getElementById('simplebox-placeholder').innerHTML = 'your 
comment text here'
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'getElementById'
```

When I changed the code to.

```
commentr.get_element_by_id('simplebox-placeholder').innerHTML = 'your comment text here'
```

The same error occurs.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users", line 73, in <module>
commentr.get_element_by_id('simplebox-placeholder').innerHTML = 'your 
comment text here'
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'get_element_by_id'
```

So I changed the code above to this.

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].getElementById('simplebox- 
placeholder').innerHTML = 'your comment text here';", commentr)
```

I got this error when I ran it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users", line 73, in <module>
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].getElementById('simplebox- 
placeholder').innerHTML = 'your comment text here';", commentr)
File "C:\Users\craandassdo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 636, in 
execute_script
'args': converted_args})['value']
File "C:\Users\craandassdo\craandassdo\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Users\craandassdo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in 
check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: 
arguments[0].getElementById is not a function
(Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.103)
(Driver info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.68 
(47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17763 x86_64)
```

*/ I Added an expected conditions module for "WebDriverWait" *

Here is the code.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
commentr = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'simplebox- 
placeholder')))
```

Here is the error associated with this code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Bsasadasd\Desktop\python\Game.py", line 74, in <module>
commentr = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'simplebox- 
placeholder')))
File "C:\Users\sadasddo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Comment: Seleniu in Python use `.find_element_by_id()` - `getElementById` is in JavaScript.
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements

Comment: Hi @furas, I believe the ID is hidden and I have to incorporate JavaScript into my code to allow the keys to send. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I appreciate your help!

Comment: you put JavaScript code in Python code - it will not work  - you have to use `driver.execute_script("code in Javascript")`. ie. `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].getElementById('simplebox-placeholder').innerHTML = 'your comment text here';", commentr)`

Comment: @furas I think we are getting places... I inserted your script and ran it. I have updated the error for you on my post. I am not familiar with JavaScript so I apologize.

Comment: you can also try run it on document , (not on selected item) `.execute_script("document.getElementById('simplebox-placeholder').innerHTML = 'your comment text here';")`

Comment: I actually ran this and it didn't have an error. But it did not input anything either.

Comment: open JavaScript console in DevTool in Chrome/Firefox and try to run it on your page. Maybe it will help you test it or find mistake in JavaScriptCode or difference in HTML

Answer (score 0):

Try the following JS code.Hope it will work.

```
 driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('simplebox-placeholder').value = 'your comment text here';")
```

Comment: I ran it and got this error. Again.                                                                   
                                                                                                                      
   `Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\sdasdasd\Desktop\python\Game.py", line 73, in <module>
    driver.executeScript("document.getElementById('simplebox- 
    placeholder').setAttribute('value', 'your comment text here')");
    AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'executeScript`

Comment: @justloookingforlove - you have to use `execute_script` instead of `executeScript` - In Python is `execute_script` but probaly in Java is `executeScript`

Comment: sorry for posted my javacode.I didn't notice python code.Now try

Comment: I have just tried this and it received no error. But it also did not input the keys. Very strange.

Comment: before apply this try to wait for the element.should work.

Comment: @KunduK I have an issue. I cannot apply an explicit wait as my "URL" has changed from the starting one, as the automation is going through pages. I would need some sort of current URL to allow the explicit wait.